# Android libstreaming error

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-mediacodec

I am using libstreaming and getting this error `"No usable encoder were found on the phone for resolution 320x240"`

I am using android 4.2.1 xolo device

```
mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
                .setContext(ctx)
                .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AMRNB)
                .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000,16000))
                .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
                .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(320, 240, 15, 500*1024))
                .setCamera(camID)
                .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
                .setPreviewOrientation(0)
                .setCallback(this)
                .build();

    // Configures the RTSP client
    mClient = new RtspClient();
    mClient.setSession(mSession);
    mClient.setCallback(this);

    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

I am using the same values in example3.

Please help me??

Thanks

Below is my log :

```
06-23 23:37:29.737: E/EncoderDebugger(1469): No usable encoder were found on the phone for resolution 176x144
06-23 23:37:29.737: E/H264Stream(1469): Resolution not supported with the MediaCodec API, we fallback on the old streamign method.
06-23 23:37:29.738: I/System.out(1469): [CDS]connect[/192.168.1.26:70] tm:90
06-23 23:37:29.740: D/Posix(1469): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.upstream :70 
06-23 23:37:29.764: D/MP4Config(1469): SPS: Z2QAH6wbGsLE5A==
06-23 23:37:29.764: D/MP4Config(1469): PPS: aOpDyw==
06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): ANNOUNCE rtsp://192.168.1.26:70/co/30/User/10 RTSP/1.0

06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): CSeq: 1

06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): Content-Length: 208

06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): Content-Type: application/sdp 

06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): Video-payload: a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000|a=fmtp:97 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001e;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAH6wbGsLE5A==,aOpDyw==;

06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): Audio-payload: a=rtpmap:99 AMR/8000/1|a=fmtp:99 octet-align=1;

06-23 23:37:29.765: I/RtspClient(1469): 

06-23 23:37:29.804: D/RtspClient(1469): Response from server: 200
06-23 23:37:29.804: V/RtspClient(1469): Sss: 45618
06-23 23:37:29.804: V/RtspClient(1469): RTSP server name unknown
06-23 23:37:29.808: D/ACodec(1469): Now uninitialized
06-23 23:37:29.813: I/OMXClient(1469): Using client-side OMX mux.
06-23 23:37:29.816: D/ACodec(1469): [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] Now Loaded
06-23 23:37:29.819: W/ACodec(1469): Use baseline profile instead of 8 for AVC recording
```

Comment: can you debug libstreaming? set VERBOSE to true in EncoderDebugger.java or go inside debug() with debugger?

Comment: @user2988855 Have you get that problem solved? I am getting the same sort of error

Answer (score 1):

VideoQuality videoQuality = new VideoQuality(352,288,15,500000);

```
    mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
            .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000,16000))
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            .setVideoQuality(videoQuality)
            .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
            .setPreviewOrientation(0)
            .setCallback(this)
            .build();
```

Please try this one. I think that resolution should be 352x288 and be careful about parameters of VideoQuality method. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that streaming is not possible on your device with the settings you have provided. You should try different combination of resolution, frame rate, bitrate, etc..

Comment: Could you post full stack trace?

Comment: @ Nickolai Astashonok i possted the log

Comment: I see, that example3 uses values, that are different to yours. Could you try example3 without any modification?

Comment: mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
.setContext(getApplicationContext())
.setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
.setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000,16000))
.setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
.setPreviewOrientation(0)
.setCallback(this)
.build(); This is from example. Your code doesn't match

Comment: i tried the example 3 first getting the same error and then i tried different combinations but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try and run example 2 from the same source. Look through logcat and see all supportet resolutions